# Scrolling of text using cairo

Tags: cairo

How to make text scrollable (horizontal and vertical) using Cairo library?
Are there any cairo API which provide scrolling functionality without the use of gtk library?

Answer (score 0):

Cairo only draws things. It has nothing to do with user interaction and thus the whole question does not really make sense, sorry.

Of course you can draw text with cairo at whatever position you want. Thus, to make text scroll you just have to redraw your text based on user input and use a slightly different position each time.